# wrapper for flash.display.textfield for StageText

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, starling-framework

I have a **textfield** in my library items. And I need the **StageText** feature of **SoftKeyBoardtype** to work on the textfield.

Is there any way to wrap the functionality of **StageText** around a **flash.display.textfield**, so that I could use the same textfield with the feature of SoftKeyBoardType enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `nativetext.as` wrapper

https://github.com/cantrell/StageTextExample/blob/master/src/NativeText.as
https://github.com/cantrell/StageTextExample/

http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2011/09/native-text-input-with-stagetext.html